# A pen-and-paper proof for a matrix implication.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, contest-math, determinant

Suppose $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & 1\\ y & 0\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} z & 1\\ w & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for $x,y,z,w \in \Bbb{R}$.

I have observed by considering many  examples of $x,y,z,w$ that:

If all the eigen values of $A^2B$ and $AB^2$ are less than one in absolute value $\implies$ $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ is not possible.

OR alternatively,

If all the eigen values of $A^2B$ and $AB^2$ are less than one in absolute value $\implies$ $\det(AB+A+I)\ge 0$ OR $\det(BA+B+I)\ge 0$

I wonder how to prove it actually?

A computational proof using computer package was shown in
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435267/proof-of-a-matrix-implication/435689#435689

But I am wondering about formal or analytical proof for this question which can be done using pen paper.

**EDIT**

**The case of $y=x$ or $z=w$ is covered by Andreas as an answer below. The only case that remains to show is whether the conjecture still holds for $y\neq x$ or $w \neq z$.**

Comment: what is it that you try to prove? what is the relation between $A$ and $B$?
Is it - find $x,y,z,w$ such that for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^2B, AB^2, |\lambda|\le 1$?

Comment: I am trying to prove: If all the eigen values of $A^2B$ and $AB^2$ are less than one in absolute value $\implies$ $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ is not possible. $A, B$ can be any companion matrices with real entries of the form shown in the question.

Comment: The word _and_ has a bit of ambiguity here. Do you mean none of $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ can be true or they both cannot be true simultaneously?

Comment: Sorry for that.. I meant to express that they both cannot be true simultaneously.

Comment: @BAYMAX Hence it would be clearer to write that $\det(AB+A+I) \ge 0$ or $\det(BA+B+I) \ge 0$. Anyway, the statement looks a bit artificial. What is the motivation behind this?

Answer (score 4):

@all who want to solve the riddle or find a counterexample:

If I made no mistake, then the eigenvalues are
\begin{align*}
2\lambda_1&=\alpha+ \sqrt{\alpha^2+4xy\alpha + 4y^2(w-x^2)}\, , \,\alpha=(x^2+y)z+x(y+w)\\
2\lambda_2&=\alpha- \sqrt{\alpha^2+4xy\alpha + 4y^2(w-x^2)}\\
2\lambda_3&=\beta +\sqrt{\beta^2+4yz\beta +4y(w^2-yz^2)}\, , \,\beta=x(z^2+w)+(y+w)z\\
2\lambda_4&=\beta -\sqrt{\beta^2+4yz\beta +4y(w^2-yz^2)}
\end{align*}
and the determinants are
\begin{align*}
\delta_1:=\det(AB+A+I)&=(x-y)z+(y+1)w+(x+1)\\
\delta_2:=\det(BA+B+I)&=(z-w)x+(w+1)y+(z+1)
\end{align*}
The statement now reads:

If all $|2\lambda_i|<2$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ then $\delta_1>0$ or $\delta_2>0.$

And to save time: $w=0\wedge z=-y$ has no counterexample according to WA.

Comment: I'm unsure how to deal with complex eigenvalues. Do we still require just $|\lambda |<1$ regardless whether they are real?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think we still need to have $|\lambda|<1$ in case of complex eigenvalues.. The problem redu es to inequalities.. I wonder if tje implication can be proved? What is WA?

Comment: I'm sure it can be solved, one way or another. But we have a four-dimensional, non-linear optimization problem, and the claim is that the feasible set is empty. That takes heavy machinery. And, there still could be a counterexample. $w=0$ would have been nice finding a counterexample, but I think that doesn't work.  WA is WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Oh okay, but computationally it has been checked to be true as per the link in the question. Now it remains to show using pen paper proof

Answer (score 4):

The claim in the question  can be rephrased by taking the inverse formulation:

$\det(AB+A+I) < 0 \qquad $ AND $\qquad \det(BA+B+I) < 0$
$\implies$ At least one eigenvalue of $(A^2B$ ; $AB^2)$ is greater or equal than one in absolute value.

As a boundary case, there are indeed situations with

$\det(AB+A+I) = 0$ ;  $\det(BA+B+I)= 0 $    ;
where at least one eigenvalue of $(A^2B$ ; $AB^2)$ equals $1 +q$ where $q > 0$.

This is e.g. achieved with values  $x = w = z = -1 $ and $y = -1-q$, then we have

$$
\det(AB+A+I) = (x-y)z+(y+1)w+(x+1)  = 0\\
\det(BA+B+I)=(z-w)x+(w+1)y+(z+1) = 0 
$$

and the characteristic equations for the eigenvalues read

$$
\det(A^2 B-\lambda I) = (z(x^2+y)+xw - \lambda)(x y - \lambda) -  (x^2+y)(xyz+wy) = (1+q -\lambda )^2 = 0 \\
\det(A B^2-\lambda I) = (x(w+z^2)+wz - \lambda) (y z - \lambda) - (xyz+wy)(z^2+w) = (1+q -\lambda )(1 -\lambda )= 0
$$

Hence we have eigenvalues $\lambda = 1+q > 1$ for both $A^2 B$ and $A B^2$.

This could also support possible contradictions to the claim, however not sufficiently. It gives rise to be able, by a continuity argument, to transport this to the  adjacent domain $\det(AB+A+I) < 0 \qquad $ AND $\qquad \det(BA+B+I) < 0$. We can look at this domain by observing

$$
\det(AB+A+I) = (x-y)z+(y+1)w+(x+1)  = (y-x)(w-z) + (x+1)(w+1) \tag{1}\\
\det(BA+B+I)=(z-w)x+(w+1)y+(z+1) =  (y-x)(w-z) + (y+1)(z+1)
$$

Hence a particularly convenient subcase is the one with $y=x$ and $w=z$. Here,  $\det(AB+A+I) < 0$ is achieved in the two cases $(x>-1 ; z < -1)$ and $(x<-1 ; z > -1)$. It is only necessary to consider one of these cases, since exchanging  $x \leftrightarrow z$ exchanges  $A \leftrightarrow B$ and this is covered by the second determinant inequality. As we are only aiming at showing that one eigenvalue will always be  greater or equal than one in absolute value, it suffices to establish one case.

We have the characteristic equation for $A^2 B$:
\begin{align}
& \det(A^2 B  - \lambda I) =
 \lambda^2 - \lambda(x z^2 + z^2 + 2 x z) - x z^2 = 0 
\end{align}

Now let $x =  -1 +a$ and $z = -1 -b$ with $a,b > 0$, then we get
$$
(\lambda-1)^2 + \lambda(-a b^2- 2 b +a) -(a - 2 b + 2a b + b^2 a - b^2) = 0
$$

which can be solved for $\lambda$. To simplify things, it suffices to notice that the equation
$$
(\lambda-1)^2 + \lambda q - (q + r) = 0
$$
has the largest solution
$$
\lambda_1 = 1 - q/2 + \frac12 \sqrt{q^2 + 4r} 
$$
Hence we have, if $r >0$, that $\lambda_1 > 1 +  (1 - {\rm sign}(q)) \; |q|/2 > 1$. Applied to the characteristic equation, this is
$$
r = (a - 2 b + 2a b + b^2 a - b^2)- (-a b^2- 2 b +a)  = b(2 a b + 2 a  - b) 
$$
hence if $2 a b + 2 a  - b > 0$ then $A^2 B$  has an eigenvalue $\lambda > 1$.

Likewise, the characteristic equation for $A B^2$ gives that if $2b - a - 2ab>0$, then $A B^2$  has an eigenvalue $\lambda > 1$.

Adding the two conditions gives $a+b$ which is $> 0$, hence it is impossible that both conditions fail (i.e. both are negative). Hence, at least one eigenvalue  of $(A^2B$ ; $AB^2)$ is greater or equal than one in absolute value.

This establishes the claim for the  subcase  $y=x$ and $w=z$. The next step is to exploit the  determinant equations **(1)** further for the case $y\ne x$ or $w\ne z$. [...]

Comment: When absolute eigenvalues of $A^2B$ and $AB^2$ are less than unity, then we cannot have $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ simultaneously. But you have just shown for the case : if $\det(AB+A+I)=0=\det(BA+B+I)$, then atleast one eigenvalue is greater than one in absolute value for matrices $A^2B, AB^2$. There are other cases of $\det(AB+A+I)>0, \det(BA+B+I)>0$. So I still think that the proof is not yet complete right?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of matrices $A,B$ where your second line of the answer holds?
If all the eigenvalues of $A^2B$ and $AB^2$ are less than one in absolute value $\implies$ $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$.

Comment: @BAYMAX You are right, there are other cases, and the inversion argument for the opposite case would only hold if all cases are covered. I edited the answer for the proof of your claim, but still there are cases left ....

Comment: Nice observation! perhaps if we could show for the cases $y \neq x$ or $w \neq z$, then we could prove the conjecture. Do you have a way?

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have started another bounty.  A way for the last case of $y \neq x$ or $w \neq z$ ?